# why did virtualenv not include all of the system paths?

Tags: python, path, virtualenv

I created a virtualenv, and while it has many system paths, it doesn't have others. Specifically, pyshared and dist-packages don't seem to be included. As a result, my system-wide MySQLdb and psycopg2 aren't available. Any ideas why?

Comment: Details: How did you create the virtualenv. what was the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be related to [Ubuntu's messing with python and virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215610/ubuntu-virtualenv-a-mess-virtualenv-hates-dist-packages-wants-site-packages)

Answer (score 1):

The only possible way that i'm aware of, is if you have created your virtualenv with the argument --no-site-packages:

from [Here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv):

> If you build with virtualenv
>   --no-site-packages ENV it will not inherit any packages from
>   /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages (or
>   wherever your global site-packages
>   directory is). This can be used if you
>   don't have control over site-packages
>   and don't want to depend on the
>   packages there, or you just want more
>   isolation from the global system.

so Here is an example to understand more:

First i will create a virtualenv normally (without --no-site-package) and you will see that
i can always access django that is installed in my system site-packages (or **dist-packages**):

```
$ virtualenv A
New python executable in A/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done
$ source A/bin/activate
(A)$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django  
>>> django.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/__init__.pyc'
```

But now i will create the virtual env using --no-site-package:

```
$ virtualenv B --no-site-package
New python executable in B/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
$ source B/bin/activate
(B)$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django
```

now you see that virtaulenv was able to access django from system **dist-packages** (**ubuntu**) in my machine.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: This would be a good answer except for the part "the only possible way", which is flat-out wrong. Ubuntu handles dist-packages (which it made up) differently than site-packages (which Debian made up), and so if you create a virtualenv using virtualenv that you installed from python's easy_install, or from python's installed pip, it won't recognize dist-packages, and on Ubuntu will display exactly these symptoms.

Comment: @freyley: sorry but i don't agree, because when you run virtualenv with __no-site-packages__ it's mean that the python interpreter in the virtualenv will not recognize any package outside the virtual env no matter where is installed (site-package, dist-packages ...) or what OS you are using, see my edit specially the part when i import the django to see that what you supposed is wrong because in my first virtualenv i import django from __dist-packages__, just to make clear i want just to help you so it's not like i want to argue or something and maybe your case is a special one .

Comment: "not like I want to argue" is funny, cause you're making an argument that I'm wrong, and "the only way" that the problem I encountered could have happened was through no-site-packages.

Comment: To be clear, singularity, I think your answer is great, except for those few words. To someone who found another way (which you admit is possible -- "maybe your case is a special one" --, those words feel like an attack. They're not helpful. "The most likely way" would have been more useful.

Comment: @freyley: sorry if i by any mean offend you , but there is a say that in my business have teach me a lot : __80 % of the bugs are from the users and not the app__, you see i was just try to help here but i guess you don't see that, but well pardon me to say this but you could have just say : " i didn't use no-site-package while creating my virtualenv" from the start than i will shut up :) , but well accept my apology if by any mean i offend you and good luck to you :)