# In buildout, include-site-packages=false is not excluding dist-packages

Tags: django, buildout

I am installing a python application on an ubuntu server. I have added include-site-packages=false in buildout.cfg but it is still not ignoring dist-packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buildout doesn't know about anything `dist-packages`, as that's a Debian and Ubuntu specific addition to Python. If buildout doesn't exclude it when you exclude `site-packages`, then is not the only package to have this 'problem'; virtualenv doesn't know about it either, see [Ubuntu + virtualenv = a mess? virtualenv hates dist-packages, wants site-packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215610/ubuntu-virtualenv-a-mess-virtualenv-hates-dist-packages-wants-site-package).

Feel free to file an issue in the [buildout issue tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/zc.buildout) to request that dist-packages is included when ignoring site-packages.

Note that on my Debian system however, the `dist-packages` directory *is* being excluded.

Buildout normally determines what the `site-packages` directories are by determining the difference between the following two commands:

```
PYTHONNOUSERSITE="x" python -c "import sys, os;print repr([os.path.normpath(p) for p in sys.path if p])"
```

and

```
python -S -c "import sys, os;print repr([os.path.normpath(p) for p in sys.path if p])"
```

If the latter still includes the `dist-packages` directory for you, then I'd classify this as a Ubuntu or Debian bug. On Debian 6.0.5, with zc.buildout 1.5.2 that path is *not* included.

The `dist-packages` directory is normally added via the [`site.py` module](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html) (which the `-S` switch above disables). Debian and Ubuntu have patched that module.

Comment: Hi Martijn, I was expecting this answer. Is there a way around?

Comment: I've included some detail as to how buildout determines what the `site-packages` paths are, perhaps you can figure this out on your own ssystem with this information. Otherwise you'd have to patch the `_get_system_paths` method in the `easy_install` module with the zc.buildout package.