# ImportError: No module named MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I am referring the following tutorial to make a login page for my web application.
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/intro-to-flask-signing-in-and-out--net-29982

I am having issue with the database.
I am getting an

```
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

when I execute

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/testdb
```

I have tried all possible ways to install python mysql, the one mentioned in the tutorial, easy_install, sudo apt-get install.

I have installed mysql in my virtual env. My directory structure is just the same as whats explained in the tutorial. The module is sucessfully installed in my system and still I am getting this error.

Please help. What could be causing this.

Comment: You've installed MySQL but have you installed the [MySQLdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.4) package for Python?

Comment: I used sudo apt-get install mysql-python. When i used pip i got Environment error for mysql_config

Comment: mysql is installed within my virtual enviroment and working properly and mysqldb has also been installed.

Answer (score 385, accepted):

If you're having issues compiling the binary extension, or on a platform where you cant, you can try using the pure python [`PyMySQL`](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) bindings.

Simply `pip install pymysql` and switch your SQLAlchemy URI to start like this:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://.....'
```

There are some [other drivers](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.pymysql) you could also try.

Comment: Did I miss something? Why isn't this listed here? Specifically that dialect name: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html. This was exactly what I had wrong though, thanks.

Comment: Note the db uri is somewhat dependent upon the connector you use :)

Comment: this didn't work with python2.7.* for me. use of `pip install MySQL-python` worked.

Comment: this one helped so much while searching after a solution for flask-sqlalchemy errors.
I faced: 
1. Error running WSGI application
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

2. (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2006, 'SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh failed')  
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

thank you very much and I hope, that others will find this solution with this error descriptions faster as I have done!

Comment: Worked on CentOS, seems to be the most non-OS-dependent answer.  Thanks!

Comment: be remember to change ` SQLAlchemy URI ` ! this works for python 3

Comment: In my case(Python Anconda 3) , your link which has other connectors worked . I used MySQL-Connector

Comment: Do not use pymysql driver because it's too slow ! ! !

Comment: It works also for MariaDB (tested for v10.4, via SQLAlchemy).

Comment: That's the answer for sqlalchemy / mysql "No module named MySQLdb" issues!!

Answer (score 104):

Or try this:

```
apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

Comment: I think the answer to the question is this

Comment: python-mysqldb has some dependencies like VC++ library and sometimes doesn't work on 64 bit OS

Comment: This worked for me too. Ubuntu 16.04 with python 2.7

Comment: For those people who this answer didn't resolve their issue this might be due to a virtualenv issue see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43984484

Comment: More accurately: `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb`

Answer (score 43):

may you try

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: Works for me on python 3.7.3

Comment: Thanks for sharing, It worked when I was using Windows but I had some issues with `mysqlclient` (`OSError: mysql_config not found`) when I was trying to run the same app on Ubuntu, the accepted answer solved it.

Comment: Works on OSX with anaconda and python 3.7.6

Comment: simple! very simple and clear.

Comment: This works on python 3.10

Comment: worked for me on MacOS + python 3.9.17

Answer (score 19):

My issue is :

```
return __import__('MySQLdb')
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

and my resolution :

```
pip install MySQL-python
yum install mysql-devel.x86_64
```

at the very beginning, i just installed MySQL-python, but the issue still existed. So i think if this issue happened, you should also take mysql-devel into consideration.
Hope this helps.

Comment: `pip install MySQL-python` yeah, that's the ticket

Comment: This depends on Microsoft Visual C++ libraries in Windows environments

Answer (score 16):

I got this issue when I was working on SQLAlchemy. The default dialect used by SQLAlchemy for MySQL is `mysql+mysqldb`.

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://scott:tiger@localhost/foo')
```

I got the "`No module named MySQLdb`" error when the above command was executed. To fix it I installed the `mysql-python` module and the issue was fixed.

```
sudo pip install mysql-python
```

Comment: before install mysql-python, you still need to install mysql or something containing the msyql_config command.

Answer (score 10):

It depends on Python Version as well in my experience.

If you are using Python 3, @DazWorrall answer worked fine for me.

However, if you are using Python 2, you should

```
sudo pip install mysql-python
```

which would install 'MySQLdb' module without having to change the SQLAlchemy URI.

Comment: If anyone is down here, and getting environment error: mysql_config not found kinda thing, then sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev can help you. Original answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5178698/2190689

Comment: If you get config parser type of error, then you may look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23978968/2190689

Answer (score 10):

So I spent about 5 hours trying to figure out how to deal with this issue when trying to run

```
./manage.py makemigrations
```

With Ubuntu Server LTS 16.1, a full LAMP stack, Apache2 MySql 5.7 PHP 7 Python 3 and Django 1.10.2 I really struggled to find a good answer to this.  In fact, I am still not satisfied, but the ONLY solution that worked for me is this...

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 libmysqlclient-dev
```

followed by (from inside the virtual environment)

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

I really dislike having to use dev installs when I am trying to set up a new web server, but unfortunately this configuration was the only mostly comfortable path I could take.

Comment: If you don't have '-dev' packages and a compiler, you cannot install any Python module which has a C extension component that needs to be compiled. Your only option would be to use a separate build box which has the extra bits and build Python wheel files. Then copy the wheels to your target system and install the packages from wheels instead.

Answer (score 6):

In ubuntu 20 , you can try this :

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
sudo apt-get install gcc
pip install mysqlclient
```

Answer (score 3):

While [@Edward van Kuik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296637)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24364863) is correct, it doesn't take into account an [issue with virtualenv v1.7 and above](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19210964).

In particular installing `python-mysqldb` via `apt` on Ubuntu put it under `/usr/lib/pythonX.Y/dist-packages`, but this path isn't included by default in the virtualenv's `sys.path`.

So [to resolve this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31658822), you should create your virtualenv with system packages by running something like:

`virtualenv --system-site-packages .venv`

Answer (score 2):

```sh
yum install MySQL-python.x86_64
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

for Ubuntu 20.04 with python3

```
 sudo apt-get install python3-mysqldb
```

by default, this work for me

#### Create a sqlite engine instance

> engine = create_engine('mysql://username:password@your_host/your_dbname')

OR

```
pip install pymysql
```

#### Create a sqlite engine instance

> create_engine('mysql://...

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue the install mySQL connector and resolved

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

more details ->
[SQLAlchemy official docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.mysqldb)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did:

First, install a python package:
`pip3 install PyMySQL`

Then add the following lines of code to your Project:

```py
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

this should fix your issue by now, the following one is optional and for anyone who is using SqlAlchemy to connect to mysql server:

Replace `engine = create_engine("mysql://YOURMYSQLURL")`
to:
`engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://YOURMYSQLURL")`

Comment: This wonderfully works for me, while others don't. Thanks!

Comment: @NamGVU ikr!!!.... I tried all the online solutions but it actually turns out the right answer was in the documentation itself.... Even ChatGPT did not recommend this answer. Upvote to help others!!

Answer (score 0):

Got so many errors related to permissions and what not. You may wanna try this :

```
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb

Answer (score -1):

I have faced this type of error when I tray to build python flask eccomerce web-application

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'?

I tray to see the version of python installed on my window 10

it was python 3.10

so MYSQL-PYTHON is compatable with the other version of python 3.8

I delet python 3.10 and I nstalled the version python 3.8

It become ok!

python --version

3.8

pip --version

python 3.8

so install the connector

pip install MYSQL-PYTHON

successfuly installed