# how to move from sqllite database to mysql database?

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlalchemy

i want to move from SQLite database M, MySQL database. if i understood correctly, so i can do it with changing the engine:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///foo.db', echo = False)
```

to:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql://username:password@localhost/ db_name (the database name) ')
```

Comment: Yes, maybe it can be done like this. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: i get this error:  "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'",  i dont know how to handel it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named MySQLdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252397/importerror-no-module-named-mysqldb)

Answer (score 0):

```
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://user:pass@some_mariadb/dbname?charset=utf8mb4")
```

or

```
engine = create_engine("mariadb+pymysql://user:pass@some_mariadb/dbname?charset=utf8mb4")
```

[sqlalchemy-mysql](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html)

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

On Ubuntu based systems:

```
apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

On RHEL/CentOS based systems:

```
yum install MySQL-python
```

On Windows:
[Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient)

Comment: what will do "?charset=utf8mb4"?

Comment: @Warrior A collation is a set of rules that defines how to compare and sort character strings. and its optional but my prefer is read https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html it'll helpful