# Install certain packages in all virtualenvs

Tags: python, virtualenv

Recently I have started to use `virtualenv`, and it has changed my life, and made so many things so much easier. However, some packages I would like available in all virtualenvs, and I haven't figured out how to do this. Is there a way to have pip install certain packages every time I create a new virtualenv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the other answers to this question are both very valuable and informative, I was looking for a solution similar to that suggested by @Sergey Gornostaev. However, I am on Ubuntu and install most of my Python packages (at least the ones I want available globally) through `apt`. That means my packages end up in `dist-packages` while `site-packages` remains empty, so I can't use @Sergey's solution. Instead, I used the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19211566/3642398).

Basically, I install the packages I want available in all environments through `apt` if possible. Then I add the following (or some variation of it) to my `.bashrc`:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

This way all those packages are available, and then I can install indivdual packages sepecifc to a given virtual environment through `pip` from within the `virtualenv`. It might not be an ideal solution, but it meets my current needs, so this is what I will be using for now.

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide.html#the-system-site-packages-option): If you build with virtualenv --system-site-packages ENV, your virtual environment will inherit packages from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (or wherever your global site-packages directory is).

Answer (score 1):

If there is a particular set you always want, which is distinct from the global site-packages collection, you could write a simple wrapper script which sets up the env, activates it, and installs those packages.

```
#!/bin/sh
virtualenv "$1"
. "$1"/bin/activate
pip install six  # f'rinstance
```

If you save this as `venvwrapper` you cound `alias virtualenv=venvwrapper` in your `.bashrc` or similar.